# Is there a way to let mypy check multiple import paths while looking for an object?

Tags: python, mypy, type-hinting

I'm working on a project where we've created a module that wraps around a third-party module (containing several submodules). The wrapper module is designed to handle certain functions internally, but also call functions from the third-party module when necessary.

I'd like to find a way to help static analysis tools, especially `mypy`, understand this situation as well as possible.

A partial solution I have found is to add to the `__init__.py` of our wrapper something like this:

```py
# wrapper_module.__init__

from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from original_module import submodule_a
    from original_module import submodule_b
    # ...

    from wrapper_module import submodule_a
    from wrapper_module import submodule_b
    # ...


# Actual code doing the imports dynamically
```

This helps in the sense that at least some imports are being correctly followed. However, the issue is that with this current naive solution, `mypy` only looks for them in the `original_module` (which makes sense, since nothing tells it how two imports with the same name should interact -- weird though that it takes the first one when you'd expect in python the second one to replace it).

Interesting note, Pycharm (almost magically) understands this exactly how I'd want: if, from another module that imports `wrapper_module`, I use `wrapper_module.submodule_a.some_function()`, it looks for `some_function` in `wrapper_module` and if it can't find it, it looks for it in `original_module` (so the "Go to implementation" function works perfectly, for instance).

Is there a way to make this work with `mypy`? Does `mypy` support following several import paths to look for dynamically imported objects (given the correct syntax to "help" it)?

Comment: It seems to me like this is a situation `mypy` might know how to handle, at least in part, for cases where we'd have `try: from a import func; finally: from b import func`. Then at least it could say that `func` can return a union of the type from `a` and the type from `b`.

Comment: Can you clarify your example? You've done both `from original_module import submodule_a` and `from wrapper_module import submodule_a`, but you say you also ran `wrapper_module.submodule_a` when `wrapper_module` is not an imported name.